# Create a method and call it from another class

Tags: unity, c#, android

Hi guys I'm having a problem of creating a custom method here's my code

```
public class Board
{
   public Board()
   {}
    public void makeMethod(string history)
    {
    intTmp_Ori = arrPart[0];
        intTmp = 10 * (intTmp_Ori / 100) + 0;

        string tmpPoint = "";
        for (i = 0; i < arrPart.Length; i++)            
        {
            if (i == 0) 
            {
                if ((int)(arrPart[i] / 100) != TIE)
                {
                    intTmp_F = (int)(intTmp_Ori / 100);
                }
                else
                {
                    intTmp2++;
                    intTmp_F = (int)(intTmp_Ori / 100);
                    bFirstTie = true;
                }
                bNextMove = false;
            }
            else    
            {
                if (bFirstTie)      
                {
                    if ((int)(arrPart[i] / 100) == TIE)               
                    {
                        if (intTmp2 < 6) intTmp2++;                             
                        bFirstTie = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        intTmp_Ori = (int)(arrPart[i]);
                        intTmp = 10 * (int)(intTmp_Ori / 100) + intTmp2;
                        intTmp_F = (int)(intTmp_Ori / 100);
                        bFirstTie = false;
                    }
                    bNextMove = false;
                }
    }
}


public class StringBuilder
{
    public StringBuilder()
    {}

    public void _StringBuilder(string history, string[] arrPartStr, int[] arrPart, int temp)
    {
        arrPartStr = history.Split(',');

        arrPart = new int[arrPartStr.Length];

        for (int c = 0; c < arrPart.Length; c++)
        {
            int temps = temp;

            if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'P') temp = 100;
            else if (arrPartStr[c][0] == 'B') temp = 200;
            else temp = 300;
            if (arrPartStr[c][1] == 'P') temp += 10;
            if (arrPartStr[c][2] == 'P') temp += 1;

            arrPart[c] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I am going to ask is how can I create that _StringBuilder Method and call it to the Board class

Comment: By the way, there already is a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the standard library. You might want to use a different name for your class to not confuse other developers about which class they are dealing with.

Comment: I'll start with the usual "You should learn C# before Unity". Unity uses a lot of high level stuff and not knowing C# before will leave you with a knowledge similar to what you would get when you tried to learn driving a car through Formula 1 races.

Comment: @Philipp it is not really a `StringBuilder` it's just the name I made . Sorry for my bad english .

Answer (score 2):

Before you can call a method on your class `StringBuilder`, you first need an instance of it.

The most straight-forward way to do so would be to create one with the `new` keyword and assign it to a variable:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
```

You can then call methods on that variable:

```
builder._StringBuilder( /* arguments */);
```

By the way, there already is a [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class in the standard library. Depending on your project organization and your imports, the compiler might get confused about which one you mean. When you encounter problems which could be explained by this, try a different name for your class.

Comment: I'm having a problem on the part the it gets me a `null reference exception error` because of the _stringbuilder part wherein it has been used first before I instantiated it . I hope you do get me . It's very hard to speak in english

Comment: @Gin09 *First* you need to create an instance, and *only then* can you call methods on it. This is really basic C# or rather object-oriented programming. It is not specific to game development. If you have further questions on this level, then you might get better and faster answers on https://stackoverflow.com

Comment: But what about the part sir on my code that `for(i = 0; i < arrPart.Length; i++)` is also in my _stringbuilder class `arrPart = new int[arrPartStr.Length];` is it alright?

Comment: @Gin09 I don't know if it is "allright" because you are not telling us what that code is supposed to do and what it does instead when you compile and/or run it.

Comment: I'm using the stringbuilder method like this `_stringbuilder();` instead of repeating it the whole time. like that sir

Comment: @Gin09 Looking at the code you posted in your question, you are not. But this should really be a question on https://stackoverflow.com, because it is about basic language syntax. It has nothing to do with game development.